# ETL Google Data cloud with SQL

Tags: sql, cloud, dataflow, google-cloud-data-fusion

I need to trafer table, function, procedure... from sql to google cloud, my question is: I should do this with Google Data Fusion or Dataflow? thanks who is gonna to answer me.

Comment: This will likely get shut down on Stack Overflow as being too broad. Take a quick look at Database Migration Service as a good starting place. It's got good detail in the documentation about what will and won't get migrated, and then places to look to do the other pieces.

Comment: You can do this with Data Fusion. See https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/reading-from-postgresql